# How do I combine multiple javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLines?

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, voip, javasound

I'm creating a VOIP server & client system, but only 1/amount of users connected of the voice packets are played. I think it's because it can only play one stream of audio from one `TargetDataLine`, and only one `TargetDataLine` per device. And I'm writing multiple audio streams to it each second.

I'm calling `line.write(t, 0, t.length);` where line is my `TargetDataLine`, and `t` is my byte array containing samples. Is there a way to combine multiple audio streams into one mono stream before redistributing between clients?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265575/playing-multiple-byte-arrays-simultaneously-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out(I was googling wrong), you just need to add the samples together, and bitwise and it to the frame size.